# wix 3.5 uninstall/upgrade from user specified directory

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer

I would like a wix based installer to uninstall or upgrade my application to a different directory than the default directory when I have done the installation to a user defined path.

I have followed the step mentioned here http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started/where-to-install and this is my wix code now in main Product.wxs

```
<Upgrade Id="{UPGRRADE-GUID}">
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" Property="NEWERPRODUCTFOUND" OnlyDetect="yes" IncludeMinimum="yes" />
  <UpgradeVersion Minimum="0.0.0" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" Property="PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED" IncludeMinimum="yes" />
</Upgrade>


<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="$(var.programDir)">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="$(var.InstallDir)"/>
  </Directory>
</Directory>

<!-- Find previous installation -->
<Property Id="INSTALLDIR">
 <RegistrySearch Id="FindInstallLocation"
     Root="HKLM"
     Key="Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\[PREVIOUSVERSIONSINSTALLED]"
     Name="InstallLocation"
     Type="raw" />
</Property>


<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <FindRelatedProducts Before="LaunchConditions"/>
  <AppSearch After="FindRelatedProducts"/>
  <RemoveExistingProducts Before="InstallInitialize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

My features access the property using following code

```
<DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
      <Directory Id="Feature1.Dir" Name="$(var.AddInName)">
        <Component Id = "Addin" Guid="COMP-GUID">
     </Directory>
</DirectoryRef>


<Feature Id="FeatureOne" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLDIR" Title="$(var.ServiceDisplayName)" Description="$(var.ServiceDescription)" Absent="allow">
<ComponentRef Id="AddIn"/>
</Feature>
```

I set the ARPINSTALLLOCATION property from mindcapers wiki about upgrade.

PROBLEM: During uninstall and upgrade it still picks up the default path for INSTALLDIR C:\Program Files\My application. Through the logs I see that INSTALLDIR is set in the Costfinalize to default path but the Feature1.Dir is set to the registry path which is the actuall uninstall path.

Can somebody suggest what to do in this case? Do I need to execute a custom action after costfinalize instead of the appsearch where the registry property is actually set?

Regards,
raj

Comment: If i pass INSTALLDIR on command line the uninstall works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have saved the original install location in the registry. Then when upgrading, you read this value from the registry into `INSTALLDIR` property.

This will have the same effect as setting `INSTALLDIR` on the command line.

There's no other *simple* method to detect where the previous version was installed. (I don't say it's impossible to determine.)